# Gimp Gif transparency issue

Tags: gimp, transparency, animation, gif

I found this gif online and I loved it but it had a white background. I've managed to get Most of it off, but now it is leaving behind a trail of each frame. I'm not sure why.

[image]

That's the Gif after I did everything. I have a picture of the issue.

[image]

That's the trail that it leaves behind.

Comment: Most likely a workflow issue. Can you show us a screenshot of the whole GIMP UI?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can see the layers are on "Cumulative layers (combine)".  So you must have done that when exporting the GIF, or whoever made the GIF saved it that way.  What you probably want is to use the "One frame per layer (replace)" option for frame disposal.

Answer (score 1):

Likely because you didn't un-optimize the image before processing (`Filter>Animation>Unoptimize`). In an "optimized" GIF, most frames are reduced to what changes from the previous frame, and superimposed over the accumulation of existing frames (in Gimp, the corresponding layers are marked `(combine)`): if the object is in front over a white background, the next frame includes a bit of white to paint over the part of the background that reappears.

Of course this requires that the image as a whole is opaque, if you use objects over a transparent background there is no way to "erase" the bits if the objects that aren't masked by the next frame. Which means that the whole image should be un-optimized: each frame totally replaces the previous one (such frames are marked `(replace)` in Gimp.

Comment: I ended up having to leave the house. when I get home ill look at it and double check everything.